# Can a bash function access and manipulate its script's command-line arguments?

Tags: arrays, bash, function, command-line-arguments

I am trying to tidy up some `bash` code. I have a bunch of lines like the example below that set variables, unless set already, using the command-line arguments given to the script.

```
[[ -z "${myvar1}" && -n $1 ]] && myvar1="$1" && shift
[[ -z "${myvar2}" && -n $1 ]] && myvar2="$1" && shift
...repeated many times...
```

I thought I'd write a function to do that and call it like this

```
positional_arg myvar1
positional_arg myvar2
```

However, this would require the function to access and manipulate the argument list. I am not sure that is possible, so this is what I came up with...

```
args=("$@")
positional_arg() {
  local value=$args
  [[ -z "${!1}" && -n "$value" ]] && eval "$1='$value'" && args=(${args[@]:1})
}
```

The problems that I am aware of with this is that

- it depends on a global `args` array being set before use
- the construct `args=(${args[@]:1})` which *shifts* the array isn't whitespace-friendly so this will not work with arguments that contain whitespace.

So, I'd like to discover if it is possible for a function to access and manipulate its script's positional arguments.

Also any alternative suggestions for implementing this fuctionality in bash would be welcome, especially if they overcome the above problems!

```
(GNU bash, version 4.3.18(1)-release)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you might want to consider using simply

```
: ${myvar1:=$1}
: ${myvar2:=$2}
# etc
```

which simply sets `myvar1` to the value (empty or not) of `$1` *only* if `myvar1` doesn't already have a non-empty value.

---

`local args=(${args[@]:1})` does not preserve whitespace, but `local args=( "${args[@]:1}")` does.

Since `$@` is used for both shell and function positional arguments, you'll sadly have to copy the shell arguments into a known global before calling your function. Of course, if you actually want to *modify* the arguments, you'll also have to copy them back after the function returns (something like `args=("$@"); my_function; set -- "${args[@]}"`).

An alternative is to pass the shell arguments as additional function arguments:

```
my-function () {
    local_args=()
    while [[ $1 != "--" ]]; do
        local_args+=("$1")
        shift
    done
    shift
    # $@ is now a copy of the shell arguments,
    # but you'll still have to copy them to a global
    # if you want to make any changes visible post-call
}
my-function arg1 args2 -- "$@"
```

Comment: Thanks for the whitespace fix! Can you explain `set -- "${args[@]}"` in your example?

Comment: @starfry, that sets the argument list (`$1`, `$2`, etc) from the `args` array.

Comment: @chepner: I originally had `${myvar1:=$1}...` but changed it because the positional parameter assignment comes after parsing options with `getopts` to fill in still-unassigned variables. Thus the variable to argument mapping changes depending on option usage. But, yes, in a consistent situation that is exactly how I'd do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the variables indirectly (without potentionally dangerous eval) in a loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

#set variables in order from "$@"
for var in myvar1 myvar2 v3 x           #names of the variables...
do
    #use one of the following to assgin to the variable
    printf -v "$var" "%s" "$1" && shift #print into variable
    #read -r "$var" <<< "$1" && shift   #read into variable
    #declare "$var"="$1" && shift       #declare a variable
done

#print the content of the variables
echo "=$myvar1=$myvar2=$v3=$x="

#or indirectly:
for var in myvar1 myvar2 v3 x
do
    echo "$var:>>${!var}<<"
done
echo "Unused/remaining args:"
printf ">>%s<<\n" "$@"
```

what for the invocation like:

```
script '1 1' 2 3 '4 4' 5 6
```

prints

```
=1 1=2=3=4 4=
myvar1:>>1 1<<
myvar2:>>2<<
v3:>>3<<
x:>>4 4<<
Unused/remaining args:
>>5<<
>>6<<
```

Anyway, using much position dependent variables is a source of the future hard-debugging... IMHO, in cases when the script must take many different variables, is better to use `getopt` and use the script as

```
script -i vali -o valo .... -z valz # ;)
```

Comment: It's always good to avoid evil `eval`! Useful tips there; I must commit at least one of them to memory. Also, I am using `getopts` before handling positional args as well. Both ways have their advantages. I just described what I'm doing in a comment to @chepner's answer. I appreciate your suggestions too, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to call `positional_arg` and pass it the command line variables with `$@`

```
positional_arg $@
```

Then you will be access the command line arguments within the function, using `$1`, `$2` etc.

`$0` will be the name of the script.

If you need to send further variables, you can simple add them after the command-line arguments.

```
positional_arg $@ $test
```

This will just increase the size of the array.

if this is an issue for you, simple add your other variables before `$@`

```
positional_arg $test $@
```

In this case, you know how many variables you are sending the function, and therefore you can make the allowances in your variable calls within your function.

`$0` in this case, still remains as the name of the script, and all other reference are increased by the number of variables you add.

In the example above `$1` before the function call, becomes `$2` within the function.

Comment: The idea was for the `positional_arg` function to eat the arg from the global list.